# Naming of an [ordered-groups] tag

Tags: discussion, tagging

It seems like there are a decent number of questions about placing some sort of order on a group. I would like to tag these questions to better organize them, but I'm not sure what to call the tag.

The phrase "ordered group" to me implies that we have a total order $\leq$ which is preserved under both left and right multiplication. But people could be asking questions about partial or lattice orders, or the ordering could be preserved only under right multiplication, etc.

Creating separate tags for each of these niche subjects seems like overkill to me, so is the standard to just call it [ordered-groups] and assume people will be able to figure out the ambiguity? One alternative would be to call it [partially-ordered-groups] and hope that people realize that even if they have a stronger restriction, they can still use the tag.

Examples:

- [Order Preserving Isomorphism](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/858975/order-preserving-isomorphism)
- [isomorphism between divisible, totally ordered, abelian groups](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/721348/isomorphism-between-divisible-totally-ordered-abelian-groups)
- [Embedding $\omega_1$ into the direct sum/product of $\Bbb R$'s and $\Bbb N$'s](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/706564/embedding-omega-1-into-the-direct-sum-product-of-bbb-rs-and-bbb-ns)
- [What motivates the definition of "Periodic" group action](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647557/what-motivates-the-definition-of-periodic-group-action)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/578365/example-for-a-partially-ordered-abelian-group

(These were taken by searching for questions tagged as both [group-theory] and [order-theory]. I filtered out the ones asking about the order of a group.)

Comment: There is also a possibility to create two tags and make them [synonyms](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-how-do-they-work).

Comment: Maybe provide a list of questions (with links) that you feel should use this tag. It would certainly help in ascertaining the viability of the tag. (Also, what would fall under the tag? Clearly not every question about the real line would, but what would the boundaries of the tag be?)

Comment: Thanks, I added some examples. @Arthur: it seems to me that if it's appropriate to add the [group-theory] tag and you care about an ordering, the [ordered-group] tag would apply.

Comment: "I filtered out the ones asking about the order of a group." -- if [ordered-groups] exists, it will be applied to such questions too. Just a warning.

Comment: Thanks for creating [tag-excerpt](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/937920/revisions) and [tag-wiki](http://math.stackexchange.com/posts/937920/revisions). (There are many users who do not bother to do that when creating a new tag.) If you plan to add the tag to some of the examples you listed in your post, keep in mind not to do [too many retags](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5068/how-much-bumping-is-too-much) in a short timespan.